# Changing color when hovering for all elements in the class

Tags: css, svg

I'm creating an interactive world map whereby when hovering on regions, the regions change color. I have a svg document and created classes to group the IDs.

When I fill on CSS, the whole class changes color, but when I .class:hover it only changes colors to the ID.

```
<style>
.NA:hover { fill: #ED0887 !important }
.LA:hover { fill: #ED0887 !important }
</style>
```

example in SVG:

```
 <path class="LA" fill="black" id="costa rica" d="m217.38,304.98l1.39,2.72l1.13,1.5l-1.52,4.51l-2.9,-2.04l- etc..
```

It should change colors for all ID's in the class.

Comment: You can't hover one item and expect it to change all the others *with the same class* or separate IDs - that's not the way CSS works.

Comment: The correct way to group SVG elements is using a `<g>`, not give them all the same class. Then you can apply the CSS to the `g` on hover...does that make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I grouped them with `<g>` in the SVG and used `g:hover` to hover over the specific combined ids. Thank you for everyone!

Answer (score 0):

I didnt understand your question at first but here is my edit:

```css
.big{
  fill:#FFFFFF;
  stroke:#000;
}
.small{
  fill: #ccc;
  stroke:#000;
}

path:hover{
  fill:#000;
  stroke:#ccc;
}
```

```html
<svg width="109.38px" height="113.5px" viewBox="0 0 109.38 113.5">

<path class="big" d="M78.5,24c41,41,40,89,0,89s-78-58-78-78S17.5,0.5,35,0.5S78.5,24,78.5,24z"/>
<path class="small" d="M47.5,43c-9,8-13,24,0,24s22,17,29,0s23-30,7-29s-11,3-19,4S47.5,43,47.5,43z"/>
<path class="small" d="M66.5,50c-0.18,0-0.39-0.01-0.63-0.02c-2.4-0.13-7.37-0.71-7.37,2.02c0,3-4,6,2,7s15-2,16-5s2-7-3-6
 S66.5,50,66.5,50"/>
</svg>
```

If you want to keep this to one specific svg then you have to give that svg a class or id:

```css
#my-svg > path:hover{
  fill:#000;
  stroke:#ccc;
}
.big{
  fill:#FFFFFF;
  stroke:#000;
}
.small{
  fill: #ccc;
  stroke:#000;
}
```

```html
<!--svg you want the hover on-->

<svg id="my-svg" width="109.38px" height="113.5px" viewBox="0 0 109.38 113.5">
<path class="big" d="M78.5,24c41,41,40,89,0,89s-78-58-78-78S17.5,0.5,35,0.5S78.5,24,78.5,24z"/>
<path class="small" d="M47.5,43c-9,8-13,24,0,24s22,17,29,0s23-30,7-29s-11,3-19,4S47.5,43,47.5,43z"/>
<path class="small" d="M66.5,50c-0.18,0-0.39-0.01-0.63-0.02c-2.4-0.13-7.37-0.71-7.37,2.02c0,3-4,6,2,7s15-2,16-5s2-7-3-6
 S66.5,50,66.5,50"/>
</svg>

<!--svg you dont want hover on-->

<svg id="other-svg" width="109.38px" height="113.5px" viewBox="0 0 109.38 113.5">
<path class="big" d="M78.5,24c41,41,40,89,0,89s-78-58-78-78S17.5,0.5,35,0.5S78.5,24,78.5,24z"/>
<path class="small" d="M47.5,43c-9,8-13,24,0,24s22,17,29,0s23-30,7-29s-11,3-19,4S47.5,43,47.5,43z"/>
<path class="small" d="M66.5,50c-0.18,0-0.39-0.01-0.63-0.02c-2.4-0.13-7.37-0.71-7.37,2.02c0,3-4,6,2,7s15-2,16-5s2-7-3-6
 S66.5,50,66.5,50"/>
</svg>
```

You could even get more specific by making groups with classes and then even more specific by giving paths classes:

```
.my-group > my-path:hover{
        fill:#000;
          stroke:#ccc;
}
```

UPDATE:

For making all the paths in the same class  hover:

```css
.my-svg:hover > path{
  fill:#0097A7;
  stroke:#ccc;
}
.big{
  fill:#FFFFFF;
  stroke:#000;
}
.small{
  fill: #ccc;
  stroke:#000;
}
```

```html
 <svg class="my-svg" width="109.38px" height="113.5px" viewBox="0 0 109.38 113.5">
    <path class="big" d="M78.5,24c41,41,40,89,0,89s-78-58-78-78S17.5,0.5,35,0.5S78.5,24,78.5,24z"/>
    <path class="small" d="M47.5,43c-9,8-13,24,0,24s22,17,29,0s23-30,7-29s-11,3-19,4S47.5,43,47.5,43z"/>
    <path class="small" d="M66.5,50c-0.18,0-0.39-0.01-0.63-0.02c-2.4-0.13-7.37-0.71-7.37,2.02c0,3-4,6,2,7s15-2,16-5s2-7-3-6
     S66.5,50,66.5,50"/>
    </svg>
```

Comment: Let me know if you have questions or if it helped you out!

Comment: Wow, thank you so much for your time! I think that that is what I was looking for, a way to group, I thought I would do this with classes. Like now you have 2 shapes with the same class. Im looking for a way to make all the paths in the same class hover at the same time when the cursor goes on one path.

Comment: Hi! I made an update for what you exactly wanted. See my answer again! Would you consider validating it if it helped you :p

Comment: Hi, thank you again, i tried your code. It seems to work on the class created for the whole svg document. The moment I add hover > path to for example the class .small, it doesn't function.

Comment: my code is only an example for the option and ways to do it. If you change the class in the css to any other class you want to use it still works.